# Choice of infinite sequence to minimize a ratio asymptotically

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, asymptotics

So suppose we consider the quantity
$$ f(t) = \frac{1 + \sum_{i=1}^t \alpha_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^t \alpha_i}$$
for an infinite sequence of positive numbers $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots$. How should the sequence be chosen to achieve the smallest $f$ asymptotically?

That is, what is the asymptotically smallest function $g(t)$ such that there exists a choice of $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots$ such that $f(t) = O(g(t))$? If such a smallest function doesn't exist, what is the limit?

For example, if we pick $\alpha_i = 1/i$, this achieves $O(1/\log t)$; but it's easy to see we can do better. However, what's the best we can do?

Comment: How about $\frac1{i\log(i)}$? Or $\frac1{i\log(i)\log(\log(i))}$, and so on?

Comment: all of these get beaten by $1/\sqrt{i}$

Comment: Do they? For example, $\alpha_i=\frac1{i\log(i)}$ gets $f(t)=O(\frac1{\log(\log(t))})$, but $\alpha_i=\frac1{\sqrt{i}}$ only gets $f(t)=O(\frac{\sqrt{t}}{\log(t)})$, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: nope: $\alpha_i = 1/\sqrt{i}$ makes the numerator about $\log t$, but the denominator will be about $\sqrt{t}$.

Comment: Right. I messed up my calculations, did the division the other way around. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: $1\over\sqrt{i\log i}$ seems to be marginally better. In questions like this, the minimum is typically never reached.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - true but it'd still be nice to see a proof that something in the log-vicinity of $1/\sqrt{i}$ is the way to go :)